# Sort PDF pages by shell script

Tags: shell, pdf

I'd like to scan huge documents using the [ADF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_document_feeder) of my scanner. Because it is not a duplex ADF, I cannot automatically scan two-sided pages. So what I do is:

1. Scan odd pages.
2. Scan even pages.

What I get is a PDF file with this page number pattern:

`1 3 5 2 4`

(How) can I sort the PDF using a shell script? There is a pattern, so that should be possible.

Comment: I think you’re asking the wrong question. You need to select a tool for manipulating the PDF; one with a good command-line interface, as opposed to one that does everything interactively. Once you have that, it should be fairly obvious what arguments to use, and you may not even need a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get you started. First extract all the pages to separate files. The get the filenames in a `bash` array. Then sort the array. Then recombine the pages.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Extract all pages as "orig-000.png", "orig-001.png"
pdfimages -png "$1" orig

# Make array of names of pages
orig=($(ls orig-*png))

echo Extracted pages:
echo @{orig[@]}

npages=${#orig[@]}
echo Pages: $npages

# ii = input index
# oi = output index
halfway=$(echo "($npages-1)/2" | bc)
oi=0
for((ii=0;ii<npages;ii++)); do
   [[ ii -eq $halfway ]] && oi=1;
   echo $ii,$oi
   out[oi]=${orig[ii]}
   ((oi+=2))
done

echo Sorted pages:
echo ${out[@]}

# Reassemble pages like this - I am suggesting ImageMagick's "convert" but your OS may have better tools
echo convert ${out[@]} sorted.pdf
```

**Output - with 9 page PDF**

```
Extracted pages:
orig-000.png orig-001.png orig-002.png orig-003.png orig-004.png orig-005.png orig-006.png orig-007.png orig-008.png
Pages: 9
0,0
1,2
2,4
3,6
4,1
5,3
6,5
7,7
8,9
Sorted pages:
orig-000.png orig-004.png orig-001.png orig-005.png orig-002.png orig-006.png orig-003.png orig-007.png orig-008.png
convert orig-000.png orig-004.png orig-001.png orig-005.png orig-002.png orig-006.png orig-003.png orig-007.png orig-008.png sorted.pdf
```

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. It could probably do with error-checking if no file is supplied, or it only has one page etc. And the intermediate files should be deleted. Good luck with your project.